# Open a FormView in insert mode only when it's empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

I have a `FormView` which I would like to open in insert mode *only if* the form contains no data. I've tried the following if statement:

```
If True Then
If SomeFormView.DataItemCount = 0 Then
    SomeFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
Else
    SomeFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit)
End If


 End If
```

but it opens in insert whether empty or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the `FormView` has been databound before doing that check, otherwise you'll always get "true" (because it does have zero items until you bind it to whatever data source is providing it with said items).  You could do this in the [databound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event, preferably:

```
SomeFormView_Databound (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SomeFormView.DataBound
{
    If SomeFormView.DataItemCount = 0 Then
        SomeFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
    Else
        SomeFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit)
    End If
}
```